# android - visible applications

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

when I push long on the middle button in android device. I see a list of applications.
considering android activity life cycle definition,
those activities are in stopped state/paused state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ! ?. They are in

## Paused State

[image]

Comment: does it depend how they went there? by middle button or by back button?

Comment: Yes, back button it is usually STOP STATE.